# Out of memory exception while running mocha test case in nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, out-of-memory, mocha.js

For unit testing I am using `mocha` & recently I am observing `out of memory exception` while running test case

```
--- Last few GCs --->

  548213 ms: Scavenge 1365.3 (1457.7) -> 1365.3 (1457.7) MB, 1.2 / 0 ms (+ 1.5 ms in 2 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
  549442 ms: Mark-sweep 1365.3 (1457.7) -> 1364.3 (1457.7) MB, 1228.6 / 0 ms (+ 2.8 ms in 4 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.2 ms) [last resort gc].
  550603 ms: Mark-sweep 1364.3 (1457.7) -> 1309.1 (1457.7) MB, 1161.4 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x30d0b01e3ac1 <JS Object>
    2: _compile [module.js:~380] [pc=0x333b9a368f36] (this=0x29e81578a591 <a Module with map 0x364941617b89>,content=0x4ec389e5fd1 <Very long string[26212]>,filename=0x31a758c32891 <String[92]: /Users/pulkit.sharva/apps/code/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js>)
    3: .js [module.js:~420] [pc=0x333b9869e18b] (this=0x1b3ffe7cfcc9 <an Object with map 0x364941655fb9>,mod...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
sh: line 1: 38263 Abort trap: 6           NODE_ENV=test istanbul cover _mocha -- --timeout 3000 -R spec --recursive test
```

is there anyway/tool through which I can determine which test case is causing this since I can see my heap size is increasing rapidly

```
code pulkit.sharva$ node --expose-gc
        > process.memoryUsage();
        { rss: 21069824, heapTotal: 9587488, heapUsed: 4520544 }
        > process.memoryUsage();
        { rss: 22892544, heapTotal: 9587488, heapUsed: 5407376 }
        > process.memoryUsage();
        { rss: 23261184, heapTotal: 10619424, heapUsed: 5785296 }
        > process.memoryUsage();
        { rss: 23560192, heapTotal: 10619424, heapUsed: 6075440 }
        > process.memoryUsage();
        { rss: 23642112, heapTotal: 10619424, heapUsed: 6158888 }
        > process.memoryUsage();
        { rss: 23715840, heapTotal: 10619424, heapUsed: 6231968 }
```

Comment: Is there many assertion in your test case, as  you can try to launch one by one with `.only()` ?

Comment: If i run the test case with .only or individually run the test case file it it all runs perfectly

Comment: I found solution, i have broken all my test suite in multiple parts  one for controllers, one for services etc, ran them separately and used istanbul-combine to collate result from individual run.

Comment: @Pulkit can you explain it in detail please.

Comment: when you run istanbul-coverage it was loading all file in memory at once since i breakdown into multiple istanbul-coverage memory consumption was low, later on I used istanbul-combine to collate the result. If you want i can add the approach as asnwer

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I don't have a great answer for why this is, but it seems like if there is an actual error in the tests themselves (missing requires, undefined function, etc.) mocha doesn't always play nice with that instead of throwing the error and killing the tests, it decides to cling onto it for dear life until a heap overflow occurs and the whole node crashes.

I was playing in our own code base and we had one section in our test setup that is like:

```html
// TODO: why do we need these?
process.on("unhandledRejection", err => {
  throw err;
});
process.on("uncaughtException", err => {
  throw err;
});
```

Because I was doing refactoring and didn't have an obvious answer, I deleted these lines, wrote a new test (with a problem accidentally) and got the overflow error just like you described. I added these lines back in and then mocha actually completed letting me know of the actual problem in the test.

Honestly I'm not 100% sure why this code seems to prevent that and would love other commenters or answers to go more in depth, but for anyone else with this problem, this might help get you unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `-p` (parallel) option from mocha fixed things for me.

Unexpectedly, removing the -p actually **reduced** the reported time my tests ran:

With Parallel (-p) option (3 runs):

1. `2762 passing (24s)`
2. `2767 passing (25s)`
3. `2767 passing (21s)`

Without Parallel

1. `2780 passing (15s)`
2. `2780 passing (15s)`
3. `2780 passing (15s)`

I am using mocha 9.2.2.

When using parallel I was also seeing this exception at the end of my test run:

```
     Uncaught error outside test suite:
     Uncaught Workerpool Worker terminated Unexpectedly
    exitCode: `1`
    signalCode: `null`
    workerpool.script: `C:\Src\ptliteui\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\worker.js`
    spawnArgs: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe,C:\Src\ptliteui\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\worker.js`
    spawnfile: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`
    stdout: `null`
    stderr: `null`

  Error: Workerpool Worker terminated Unexpectedly
      exitCode: `1`
      signalCode: `null`
      spawnfile: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`
      stdout: `null`
      stderr: `null`

      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (node_modules\workerpool\src\WorkerHandler.js:294:13)
      at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```